# How can I find out if Nautilus uses copy/move validation?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, checksums

Normally I use `rsync` or `rdiff-backup` to copy or move large amounts of files around with validation activated.

I don't know if Nautilus uses some kind of verification on copy or move commands.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present there is no setting in nautilus for validating copied files.

Nautilus does have a [Brainstorm page](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/nautilus/) for ideas so maybe you can add your request there.

Comment: Okay, Thank you, now I know the answer but not the way for further explaining myself this question with a newer version.